# How to get text after tag within li element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to get the text within a `<li>` element that I identify with help of `span` elements that contain "Inhalt:".

The text I want to get is "0,75l".

This is the HTML code:

```
<li class="product--tax is-left">
   <span class="label--purchase-unit">Inhalt:</span>
0,75 l #text I want to get
</li>
```

If been trying this, however it doesn't seem to work:

```
doc.search("[text()*='Inhalt:']").parent.xpath('text()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find the text node that follows the `<span>`. That's easily done once you know where the `<span>` is:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)

<li class="product--tax is-left">
   <span class="label--purchase-unit">Inhalt:</span>
0,75 l
</li>
EOT
```

These are various ways to get there:

```
doc.at('li span').next_sibling.text.strip # => "0,75 l"
doc.at('li.product--tax span.label--purchase-unit').next_sibling.text.strip # => "0,75 l"
doc.at('.label--purchase-unit').next_sibling.text.strip # => "0,75 l"
doc.at('span.label--purchase-unit').next_sibling.text.strip # => "0,75 l"
```

Moving on...

```
doc.search("[text()*='Inhalt:']").parent.xpath('text()')
```

is a bad way to go about trying to find the node:

- `search` returns a NodeSet, which would be all matching nodes in the document. While this particular use might only have one occurrence of "Inhalt:", in another document that has multiple instances of the target word you'd get multiple hits and would get a garbage result.
- `parent` isn't a method of NodeSet, so that'd blow up.
- `parent.xpath` isn't a good way of continuing a selector. Instead, to accomplish that in XPath you should use something like:

  ```
  [text()*='Inhalt:']/../text()
  ```

  `..` means move to the parent of the current node in XPath-lingo. That's off the top of my head but looks right.

---

> Why do you use at instead of .css or .xpath?

`at` is equivalent to `search('some_selector').first`, so it's the shorthand to find the first occurrence of that selector. `at` and `search` are generic methods, taking either XPath or CSS, and rely on some heuristics to determine whether the selector is an XPath or a CSS string. They *can* be fooled but most of the time they're completely safe and more convenient than their `xpath`, `css`, `at_xpath` or `at_css` variants.

If the markup could have multiple nodes you want to identify then adjust the use of `at` and `search` accordingly.

There is a point of confusion we see people fall over regularly. `at` and the `at_*` variants return a Node, and `search` and its `xpath` and `css` variants return a NodeSet. When trying to extract text from the search `text` will do something unexpected. Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"

doc.at('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at('p').text # => "foo"

doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

This behavior is documented but people rarely read that information, then try to figure out how to recover the text of the two nodes after it's been mangled.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Why do you use at instead of .css or .xpath? :)

Comment: Glad it helped. The idea on Stack Overflow is we're writing an on-line reference book, so good questions and answers help the rest of the programming world. Not only does it help you, it helps the next person looking for a solution to a similar problem. Keep asking good questions, then start answering them and teaching them what you've learned.